# Config error Laravel 5.5 admin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laraadmin, laravel-admin

I have just integrated [laravel-admin](http://laravel-admin.org/docs/#/en/installation) in my Laravel project. When I try to get login then it shows me an error message at the top of every inner pages.

Please check the screenshot:

[image]

And here is the **'disks'** array from my **filesystems.php**:

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],

    ],
```

I have tried to find out the issue but nothing helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be you need to add admin to disks array like this

```
'disks' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],

    ],
```

Comment: can you please let me know one more thing, is this admin panel a good idea to use?

Comment: I have never used it. just went through code to find an answer for your question.

Comment: okay any recommendation from you? i mean which admin panel you think is good for laravel 5.4 or 5.5

Comment: never used an admin panel that much. i think any would be fine. look at the packagist/ github download counts, favourites and contributors etc.